# How does NSAttributedString follow the MVC paradigm?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, nsattributedstring

Can anyone explain to me how NSAttributedString correctly follows the MVC paradigm? I know it doesn't inherit from NSString, but it still is a string, so I would say that's part of my model. However, setting UI attributes such as underline, font, shadow, etc. clearly are part of the View when talking MVC, so I'm not really sure how this follows the rules.

Comment: Who says it must conform to MVC?

Comment: Most of Apple's stuff is MVC-compliant, so it would make sense that `NSAttributedString` would be as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSAttributedString is a model class.

It just has the representation of the attributed string.

Just because it stores the attributes, that doesn't make it responsible for the display of the attribute.

Imagine you had a custom class for shapes. If you had a square shape and stored it's colour, it would still be a model object, because it's up to the presenting view to draw the square and fill it with the colour, the model object is just a place to store the attributes.

Comment: That does make sense, but why wouldn't they make these attributes part of the views that show the strings? Most of the text shown in UIKit, as far as I know, is based on `UILabel`s, so why didn't they give them the capability of displaying those attributes? Now if, for example, I want a green underlined text, I set the color on the UILabel, and the underline on the string itself. Doesn't really seem consistent?

Comment: The `textColor` attribute is a convenience that edits the underlying `attributedString`; if you wanted to change both the underline and the color in one place you would create an attributedString with the style you wanted and set it using the `attributedString` property on the UILabel.  The idiom they use makes the relationship between the different text classes more obscure for the sake of convenience, but under the hood its MVC.

Answer (score 2):

`NSAttributedString` provides infrastructure and is the superclass for Cocoa's styled text model class, `NSTextStorage`.  An `NSTextStorage` is just an `NSAttributedString` that can talk to layout managers and does some bookkeeping/convenience methods with regard to editing.

The controller duties are handled by `NSLayoutManager`.  Alot of this has to do with turning unicode strings into glyphs, styling them and doing the various geometry calculations.  It does all of this with regard to `NSTextContainer` objects, which (in the base class's case) are just fancy `NSSize`s the layout manager can use to calculate where a glyph should be stroked, where line breaks should happen, etc.

Cocoa's view class for styled text is `NSText` and its subclasses, working with the rulers, font and color panels.  `NSTextView` is an `NSText` subclass, and `NSCells` share an `NSText` object to edit their content.  `NSText` is an `NSResponder` and it accepts text editing messages for its textStorage and layoutManager, if present.